# Where can I get the FirefoxDriver for WebDriver?

Tags: python, firefox, webdriver

Google Chrome has a `ChromeDriver` available [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/downloads/list). I cannot find the equivalent for Firefox. (Which I think is necessary to make `ActionChains` working.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firefox Driver comes with Selenium/Webdriver itself.  No need to launch an external server (like Chromedriver).  It is all built-in.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver

Comment: note:  as of selenium 3.0, FirefoxDriver has been replaced by GeckoDriver (which is external)